# IE-11 not redirecting script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, internet-explorer-11

We have a web app that requests javascript from a Node API, which in some cases redirects to a script from another server. The request is made from HTML, something like this:

```
<script src="https://our-api.our-domain.com/some-script.js" async></script>
```

and the response from `our-api` contains the following headers, among others:

```
status: 302 (temporary redirect)
location: https://another-api.another-domain.com/actual-script.js
```

This works fine in Chrome, but IE-11 hangs. I have verified that `our-api` is consistently sending the 302 response and the redirect url.

Chrome shows the 302 response (`Network` tab) from our API, then goes on to request `actual-script.js`. You can see that come back with status 200, and the script runs as expected.

IE-11 shows the request being made, but it stays in a "Pending" state with no indication that the 302 was ever received by the browser, but no error either. After about a minute, the request apparently times out, and network tab shows the request as "Aborted".

I've tried clearing the cache. No joy. Thinking that perhaps this is considered a security risk by IE, I also tried listing both `*.our-domain.com` and `*other-domain.com` as trusted, but that doesn't help either.

What do I need to do to make IE honor the redirect?

**Addendum:**

I conducted a couple of experiments locally, and found that IE-11 never requests the redirect url `actual-script.js` at all. It will honor the redirect for `<img>` and `<link>` tags, but not for `<script>` tags. Ugh.

Comment: Of course, we would rather not. All our devs hate IE. But that requirement is driven by the market. Our customers are businesses, and most of them still use IE.

Comment: @JoelLee I completely understand that. I was giving a jQuery fixes everything solution. (Don't forget you can still back out, even a lot of Google products require better than IE!)

Comment: Sound like to me either a cache or header issue.  I'm pretty sure IE doesn't allow headers at all.  Meaning the JS has to be located in the same location.

Comment: @Grant Actually, the example code I have shown gets pasted, along with some HTML, into websites that we do not control. It has to work in IE-11. I was trying to avoid explaining the complexities.

Comment: @William Not sure what you mean by IE doesn't allow headers. The only headers I would be touching are response headers from our server. The JS definitely does not have to come from the same server as the HTML.

Comment: @JoelLee oh ok. So would this be an iframe or are they actually copy and pasting the code?

Comment: @Grant Not an Iframe.

Comment: @JoelLee ok, because that would definitely change the whole question.